# TDS: Sync Project with Sitecore for entire solution

Tags: helix, tds, serialization

I am working on a large Sitecore solution based on the Helix principles, with +20 different TDS projects. In general this works fine, but if one of the developers changes a value for a "Deploy Once" item, it is difficult to update the item across all developer machines.

Our usual process is to do a "Deploy" on the solution, but this does not update "Deploy Once" items if they are already there. Instead we have to sync each TDS project using the "Sync Project with Sitecore" option.

Is there a way to sync all projects, perhaps by forcing Sitecore to be updated with all TDS items, even the items with "Deploy once"?

Comment: We're facing the same issue. As of TDS version 5.6.0.8 there is the option of "Quick Push" to Sitecore. This is only available to a single project, but I was promised by an Hedgehog employee, that they are working on a  solution for all projects. This obviously only works for local dev machines.

Comment: Hedgehog have received requests for features like this, and always work to improve and add new features to the products with new releases. There will be some news very soon on this exact topic.

Comment: @SeanHolmesby: Could you create an answer for this question so that I can close it? I strongly believe that the features in TDS 5.7 solves my issues, with the introduction of solution wide sync and lightning sync. I haven't tried them, but if the features works as described, it would solve my issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TDS Classic 5.7 (released after this question was initially posted) now has a 'Sync all projects with Sitecore' feature. This is a context menu option on the solution (under the Team Development for Sitecore group) when you have TDS 5.7 installed, and allows you to run a sync across all TDS projects in the solution.
https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/TDS-Classic-5-7
[image: Sync all projects with Sitecore]

Obviously, with many projects, and therefore, likely many items, this Sync could take a long time. Therefore, TDS Classic 5.7 also introduces a 'Lightning Sync Mode' (found within the TDS Options in the Visual Studio Options dialog), which saves comparison time by only comparing the Revision IDs of the TDS and Sitecore items, and not all of the fields.
https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/tds-classic-5-7-lightning-mode
[image: Lightning Sync Mode]

On top of this, your question specifically asks about force-updating the Sitecore items, even those with 'DeployOnce' set. TDS Classic 5.7 also introduces the 'Quick Push all TDS Projects' feature in the solution context menu. This does exactly that, it pushes every item, in every project, to your Sitecore instance, even those with 'DeployOnce'. 
[image: Quick Push all TDS Projects]

So instead of doing a 'Sync with Sitecore' -> select all -> select 'Update/Add to Sitecore' -> click 'Do Updates', you can now save the sync comparison time and a couple of those clicks by using the Quick Push feature instead.